# Getting PDF file from Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, download

I have generated a PDF object from scratch using PDFjet in a Java Applet i.e. I did NOT generate it on the server. But how can I invoke a "file download" prompt to serve this PDF without sending it to the server? I do not have a HTTPRequest or response.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options I can think of for saving the document to disk.

1. Digitally sign the applet, get the user to accept the trusted code when prompted, offer the user a file chooser to specify a location, then save it to that location.
2. Use the [JNLP API files services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) to do basically the same thing.